# Is there any way/workaround that I can feed the aggregate results in RethinkDB

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I have an aggregate query and I want to feed to the change of aggregated result. For example:

```
r.table('logs').group('message').count().changes()
```

Obviously the above command failed.

Is there any workarounds that I can feed to the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changefeeds on aggregations aren't supported in the current version of RethinkDB, unfortunately.  You'd have to do `r.table('logs').changes()` and do the aggregation yourself in the client.

You can track progress on adding this feature at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1118 .

Comment: So sad. Wish you could accelerate this.

Comment: Do you think Druid.io can be added to the stack as a work around?